Intelij mantine breakpoints not found
we using mantine components inside our react project, I have register mantine breakpoints with help of mantine documentation and it looks like this:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-preset-mantine': {},
    'postcss-simple-vars': {
      variables: {
        'mantine-breakpoint-xs': '480px',
        'mantine-breakpoint-sm': '768px',
        'mantine-breakpoint-md': '1024px',
        'mantine-breakpoint-lg': '1440px',
        'mantine-breakpoint-xl': '1920px',
      },
    },
  },
};

From code prespective everything is fine, those vars is being seen in .module.css but Intelij dont see it and inform me constantly about error

Is There ANY solution for this kind of problem?

Please try choosing PostCSS dialect in Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Style Sheets | Dialects.
